What is the most appropriate strategy for deploying Azure Functions app with a customer Docker container?
I'm working on a C# .NET Azure Functions app.
This app follows a common pattern: Http Starter, Durable Orchestrator, Activity Function. Activity function requires access to "Simba Spark ODBC Driver" in order to retrieve data from Azure Databricks Sql Warehouse. Because Azure Functions are "serverless", this Activity function needs to be deployed to run in a custom Docker container, which will have this ODBC driver installed and configured. I have two questions related to packaging and deployment of this app:

Given that only one out of three functions in this app requires a customer container, should I deploy this function as a separate functions app and have the other two functions in a separate app? If I did this, how will the Durable Orchestrator be able to invoke the Activity function which belongs to a different functions app?

If I was to build a single custom Docker container to host all three functions within a single app - how would the horizontal scaling be accomplished since all three functions would have to be replicated instead of just the Activity function?


Another words - what is the most appropriate packaging and deployment strategy for this use case?
Here are the functions:
OrchestratorStarter.cs:
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace DurableOrchestratorDotnet8Linux
{
    public static class OrchestratorStarter
    {
        [Function("Orchestrator_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
            [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("Orchestrator_HttpStart");

            // Function input comes from the request content.
            string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
                nameof(Orchestrator));

            logger.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);

            // Returns an HTTP 202 response with an instance management payload.
            // See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api#start-orchestration
            return await client.CreateCheckStatusResponseAsync(req, instanceId);
        }
    }
}

Orchestrator.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

namespace DurableOrchestratorDotnet8Linux
{
    public static class Orchestrator
    {
        [Function(nameof(Orchestrator))]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(nameof(Orchestrator));
            logger.LogInformation("Invoking activity function.");
            var outputs = new List<string>();
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(ActivityFunction), "Databricks"));
        
            return outputs;
        }

        
    }
}

Activity.cs (the one which needs the customer container to gain access to the ODBC driver):
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace DurableOrchestratorDotnet8Linux
{
    public static class ActivityFunction
    {
        [Function(nameof(ActivityFunction))]
        public static string RetrieveDatabricksData([ActivityTrigger] string name, FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("SayHello");
            logger.LogInformation("DB Warehouse Saying hello to {name}.", name);

            var connectionString = "DSN=DatabricksWarehouse";
            var query = "SELECT c.customer_id, c.customer_name, c.customer_email, o.order_id, o.product, o.amount" +
                     " FROM Customers c" +
                     " JOIN Orders o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id";

            List<string> records = new List<string>();

            try {
                    using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            connection.Open();

                            using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(query, connection))
                            {
                                using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                                {
                                    while (reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        string record = reader.GetString(0) + " " + reader.GetString(1) +
                                                        " " + reader.GetString(2) + " " + reader.GetString(3) +
                                                        " " + reader.GetString(4) + " " + reader.GetString(5);
                                        records.Add(record);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            logger.LogError($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
                            name = ex.Message;
                        }
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
                name = ex.Message;
            }
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }
    }
}

Dockerfile (with the ODBC driver installed):
# Use the official Microsoft Azure Functions base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4.0-appservice

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl apt-transport-https unixodbc-dev libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 
# Copy the local Simba Spark ODBC Driver .deb file into the image
COPY simbaspark_2.8.0.1002-2_amd64.deb /tmp/simbaspark_2.8.0.1002-2_amd64.deb
COPY ./ini/odbc/* /usr/local/odbc/
COPY ./ini/simba.sparkodbc.ini /etc/
 
# Install dependencies required by Simba Spark ODBC Driver
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit
 
# Install the Simba Spark ODBC Driver
RUN dpkg -i /tmp/simbaspark_2.8.0.1002-2_amd64.deb && \
    apt-get install -f -y && \
    rm /tmp/simbaspark_2.8.0.1002-2_amd64.deb
 
# Set environment variables for ODBC
ENV ODBCINI=/usr/local/odbc/odbc.ini
ENV ODBCSYSINI=/usr/local/odbc/
ENV SPARKINI=/etc/simba.sparkodbc.ini
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
 
# Copy the function app files to the image
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot
 
# Expose the port Azure Functions runtime listens to
EXPOSE 80


@EugeneI Goldberg dont think it is possible currently. check this github  link https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/158

Currently it is not possible in Azure Function.
As Mentioned in this github link
I tried doing same but getting error.

I deployed Durable_orchestrator(Http Trigger) function and Orchestrator function in same docker container
Activity function in different Docker Container.
And tried to trigger using URL of the activity Function. but it is throwing error.
It is not triggering Activity trigger

My code :
function1.cs:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(nameof(Function1));
            logger.LogInformation("Saying hello.");
            //var activityUrl = "https://activityfunc.azurewebsites.net/api/SayHello";

            var activityUrl = "http://localhost:34877/api/SayHello";
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(activityUrl);
            outputs.Add(response);
            // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
            return outputs;
        }

        [Function("Function1_HttpStart")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
            [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("Function1_HttpStart");

            // Function input comes from the request content.
            string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
                nameof(Function1));

            logger.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);

            // Returns an HTTP 202 response with an instance management payload.
            // See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api#start-orchestration
            return await client.CreateCheckStatusResponseAsync(req, instanceId);
        }
    }
}


Activity.cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Activity
    {
        [Function("SayHello")]
        public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("SayHello");
            logger.LogInformation("Saying hello to {name}.", name);
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }

    }
}


OUTPUT:


